# Finding all records containing a given subfield in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql

In mongodb, i can find all those records in a collection in database db that contain a particular field using the following query

```
var doc = db.collection_name.find({field_name:{$exists:true}})
```

Now consider the following document:

```
{
  "somefield":"someval",
  "metadata": {"id":"someval",
               "client_url":"http://www.something.com"

              }
}
```

What would be the query for getting all records having the id field in metadata ?

Please Help.
Thank You

Answer (score 33):

You can use dot notation to reference sub-document fields

```
var doc = db.collection_name.find({"metadata.id":{$exists:true}})
```

Comment: You can also write it as: `db.collection_name.find({metadata: {id: {$exists: true}}})`.

Comment: @AlejandroGarcíaIglesias your solution seems to work only from version 4.4 (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)