# MongoDB: filter records by checking if subfield keys include a specified set

Tags: mongodb

I have records in a MongoDB collection with the following structure:

```
{
    'field1': {
        'a': 3,
        'b': 1,
        'c': 4,
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to find all records for which the keys in `field1` are in the following set: `['a','b']`.

How can I structure a MongoDB query which will do this?

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767949/finding-all-records-containing-a-given-subfield-in-mongodb) describing how to find all records which have a particular subfield. I would like to do the same, but testing for multiple subfields.

Thanks!

EDIT: I am aware I could write a query of the following form:

`{'$and': [{'field1.a': {'$exists': true}, {'field1.b': {'$exists': true}]}`

However, I would like to find a way to pass in a list of the subfield keys I'm looking for, instead of adding another `$exists` for each additional key.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to the issue you were facing? I just updated my answer to reflect the fact that you can generate a query without the explicit `$and` operator, which makes the solution a bit simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any MongoDB query that would be able to do this automatically. However, if you're willing to take advantage of the JavaScript available in the `mongo` shell, you can generate the `$and` query dynamically, which could be helpful. For example, given your sample data, you could do something like the following:

```js
var q = { "$and" : [] };
var arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
for (key in arr) {
    var field = "field1." + arr[key];
    var clause = {};
    clause[field] = { "$exists" : true };
    q["$and"].push(clause);
}
db.collection.find(q);
```

This would definitely be easier to run than editing the query manually every time you add a key.

**[EDIT]**

Note that you do not need to use an explicit `$and` in the query, but just separate the clauses with commas. From [this page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) in the documentation.

> MongoDB provides an implicit AND operation when specifying a comma separated list of expressions. Using an explicit AND with the $and operator is necessary when the same field or operator has to be specified in multiple expressions.

This means that you can generate a simpler query as follows:

```js
var q = {};
var arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
for (key in arr) {
    var field = "field1." + arr[key];    
    q[field] = { "$exists" : true };    
}
db.collection.find(q);
```