# Finding all records containing any kind of subfield in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nested, find, field

I have a question similar to [Finding all records containing a given subfield in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767949/finding-all-records-containing-a-given-subfield-in-mongodb), but where you don't know the subfield name.

Given the following documents:

```
// Document 1
{
   age: 10,
   name: "andrew",
   meta: {
      meta1: true
   }
}
```

and

```
// Document 2
{
   age: 10,
   name: "andrew",
   meta:{
   }
}
```

I want a query that will find documents that have a value defined for any property inside the `meta` field. In this case, such a query would only match `Document 1`.

I tried the following:

```
db.col.find({ meta: { $ne: "" } })
```

But it matched all documents including ones where `meta` had no subfields.

I only want documents with something inside meta.

I've been struggling searching and trying, but nothing.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `db.col.find({meta: {$ne:{}}})`?

Comment: wow right... feeling so dumb right now -.- write as an answer please, i would be grateful to accept it, thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply:

```
db.col.find({meta: {$ne:{}}})
```

You were very close!